# Get object by field other than primary key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Hi I'm new to both Django and the Django-Rest-Framework. I've gone through the tutorials. What I'm trying to do (as a learning exercise) is return an object based off a field other than the primary key.

- `myserver:8000/videos` returns a list of all videos.
- `myserver:8000/videos/1` returns the video with primary key of 1

What I would like to do is:

- `myserver:8000/videos/:videoname` returns the video where `videoname = videoname`

I have the following Videos model:

```
class Videos (models.Model):
    videoID = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    videoName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    class Meta:
        app_label="quickstart"
```

My router is configured as:

```
video_detail = views.VideoDetailView.as_view({
    'get':'list'
})

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^videos/(?P<videoName>[^/]+)/$', video_detail)
)
```

And my view is defined as:

```
class VideoDetailView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = VideosSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        videoName = self.kwargs.get(videoName, None)
        queryset = super (VideoDetailView,self).get_queryset()
        if videoName:
            queryset = queryset.filter(videoName=videoName)
        return queryset
```

The api runs but when I hit: `myserver:8000/videos/SecondVideo/` (where "SecondVideo" is the name of the video) I get a 404 error.

Any help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I figured it out.  What was going on was the

```
router.register(r'videos', views.VideosViewSet)
```

Was handling `myserver:8000/videos/1` and so my a new url pattern   `url(r'^videos/(?P<videoName>.+)/$', views.VideoDetailView.as_view())` was being overridden by the registered route.  The code that works is:

```
urls.py

url(r'^video/(?P<videoName>.+)/$', views.VideoDetailView.as_view())

views.py

class VideoDetailView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = VideosSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        videoName = self.kwargs['videoName']
        return Videos.objects.filter(videoName=videoName)
```

This [documentation page](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering.html#filtering-against-the-url) on filtering against the URL helped me piece together what was going on.

Comment: This is definitely not the best answer. Basically you figured out you had a bug in your code and upvoted yourself because of this. Very lame. Downvoted.

Answer (score 21):

Try setting the `lookup_field` attribute on your view class. That is the field that will be used to look up an individual model instance.  It defaults to `'pk'` but you can change it to `'videoName'`.

```
class VideoDetailView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = VideosSerializer
    lookup_field = 'videoName'
```

Comment: I went ahead and added the lookup_field and I still get a 404.  Any other ideas?  Or reasons why this wouldn't be working?

Comment: This worked for me once I got the URL right. For people new to Django, here's the URL you would use to look up a video where videoName = 'SecondVideo': http://localhost:8000/videos/SecondVideo/?format=json

Answer (score 3):

What about a solution just like this:

views.py

```
class VideoDetailView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = VideosSerializer
    lookup_field = 'videoName'
```

reasoning:
you want a detailview, so there is no need for `ListView` but `RetriveAPIView`

if some furthere manipulation will be needed just override `get_object` method like this:

```
def get_object(self):
    obj = super(VideoDetailView, self).get_object()
    # perform some extra checks on obj, e.g custom permissions
    return obj
```

Answer (score 3):

Credit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWZB_F32BDg

Use **lookup_field** to define the field used for querying the table and **look_up_kwargs** for the field in the url

`url(r'^videos/(?P<videoName>[^/]+)/$', video_detail)`

```
class VideoDetailView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = VideosSerializer
    queryset = Videos.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'videoName'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'videoName'
```

Answer (score 3):

Using **ModelViewSets** you can use **@action** decorator you can define specific method if you don't want to change the complete lookup behavior of the viewset and serializer. For example:

```
class VideoDetailView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Videos.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideosSerializer

    @action(detail=True)
    def video_name(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Video.objects.get(videoName=pk) # pk will be the video name
        serializer = VideosSerializer(queryset, many=True) # You can specify other serializer if you want here
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Then, your url will be:
myserver:8000/videos/SecondVideo/video_name/

You can read more in: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/