# Passing params between angular and django rest framework

Tags: python, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

My angular factory is as follows:

```
factory("GetUser", ["$resource",function($resource) {
   return $resource(
     "api/v1/user/:username",
     {},
     {
        "query": {
           method: "GET",
           headers:{
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
           }
         }
     },
     {
        stripTrailingSlashes:false
     }
   );
}]);
```

My api urls.py is as follows:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from .views import UserViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(prefix='user', viewset=UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

My view.py is as follows:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = user.objects.all()
   serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

I am new to python and I was wondering how I can be able to retrieve the parameter written **username** that I am sending from Angular js. Tutorials I keep getting are showing how to get all the fields using **queryset = user.objects.all()** as shown in the views.py. How can I change the views.py so it return I object.

Comment: Did you try solution provided here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386859/get-object-by-field-other-than-primary-key)? In your case it would be defining attribute as `lookup_field="username"` assuming that your field in database is also called username

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was exactly looking for.

Comment: I turned my comment into answer so if you find it satysfying you can accept it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try solution provided here ([Get object by field other than primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386859/get-object-by-field-other-than-primary-key))? In your case it would be defining attribute as `lookup_field="username"` assuming that your field in database is also called username